# Not able to get crash reports in iTunes connect for a live application in AppStore

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I have developed an App & uploaded to AppStore.The app is live now. For some users the app is crashing still i am not able to get crash logs in my iTunes connect Account by which the application is uploaded.

Can any one help me finding the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How long has the app been published? It will take some time for the data to appear in iTunes Connect.

Comment: an other point, your users might not have enable sending crash reports

Comment: app is live since past 8 months

Comment: Jerome Diaz: Can you please explain how to enable sending crash reports in iTunesConnect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Apple does... *something* with the crash reports before it delivers them to you. It seems to aggregate them somehow, though it's not clear whether this is a process designed to be helpful or just a bug. There's not much you can do; being patient *might* help. Your best bet is a helpful user telling you when the crash occurs.

The only sure way to get all the crash reports -- and this doesn't really help you right now -- is to include your own crash reporting code. [I wrote about my experience](http://www.zx81.org.uk/computing/opinion/why-you-need-a-crash-reporter.html) on my blog.

Answer (score 1):

For crash reports from Apple via iTunes **users have to actively enable crash reporting** to Apple - otherwise no reports are sent. For all my apps I saw almost no crash reports, so my guess is most users don't allow crash reports to be sent to Apple.

Your best bet is to include some **third party tool** for crash reporting (e.g. [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com) or, to an extent, [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com)) or do it yourself.