# iOS Crash Report Service

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, crash-reports

My concern is to improve my app by collecting crash reports via the crash report service in iOS. For internal testing I uploaded a beta version of it using Xcode, containing a built-in error throwing NSRangeException. After archiving and uploading the app to the store it was installed on an iPhone 5s running iOS 9.3.3 using TestFlight. In my opinion I followed all the steps described **[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html)**, but with no success.

In the diagnostic settings of the device, automatic crash reporting is enabled and I can see various crash logs (>10) caused by my app. On the iTunes Connect website I see only three overall crashes and just one is shown in the Xcode Organizer. Even after syncing the device through iTunes nothing changed.

Contacting Apple-Support didn´t help either. because they had  *"very little information available".*

For stability improvement I need to make the crash reports available, so I have a couple questions:

> 1. Which steps are done internally by the crash reporting service and how long does it take to see some results? (As mentioned in iOS developer library documentation it can take up to three days, which are long overdue by now).
> 2. Are the reports caused by the same error gathered and reported as a single entry? If not what is the procedure?

I already searched for some similar questions and came up with the following information:

- [Users say that the iOS app crashes without any further explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588072/users-say-that-the-ios-app-crashes-without-any-further-explanation)
- [Not able to get crash reports in iTunes connect for a live application in AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164190/not-able-to-get-crash-reports-in-itunes-connect-for-a-live-application-in-appsto)
- [I can not get a crash report in iTunes Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241695/i-can-not-get-a-crash-report-in-itunes-connect)
- [submit crash logs to Apple via iTunes Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208557/submit-crash-logs-to-apple-via-itunes-connect)
- [How do you view TestFlight crash logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728516/how-do-you-view-testflight-crash-logs)

I hope somebody has deeper insight or already gained more experience using Apple`s Crash Report Service and could share this information. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why don't you try Crashlytics?

Comment: I am aware of Crashlytics and it's advantages over the crash report service, but before embedding some 3rd party library I wanted to verify whether it is pointless to use Apple's solution.

Comment: I've also heard HockeyApp is pretty good. I work for Sentry as well (we also do crash reporting for iOS, as well as all the other languages).

Answer (score 1):

[Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/ios) may be a good choice.
It can collect you crash report, and give a crash description.

Comment: As far as I know Crashlytics mentioned by @Vishal Sonawane is part of Fabric and seems a good choice. Nevertheless is the crash report service so bad or just unpopular by the most people?